# Windows 8 Pro NAS not recognized?

Tags: networking, windows-8, nas, smb

Some time ago I upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Pro x64. Everything works fine, but my Netgear ReadNAS Duo won't show up anywhere besides in the router control panel. There I can see that it has been given an IP and is running (I used SMB under Windows 7 to connect).

Has anyone experienced something like that and knows how to fix it?

Comment: If you know the IP, can you ping it and does it reply? If so, there is a chance it is the AV (my Kaspersky is a pest in stopping the connection)

Comment: Ping works fine without loss

Comment: I will try that now...

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few ideas, each is separated by a line. Hopefully one of these will work for you.

---

Since a ping returns, I would suspect you need to type that IP into your browser to access the NAS home page.

From here, you should be able to login and set permissions.

---

Downgrade to an earlier version, like 4.2.21

For your [Readynas and Windows 8 issues see this link](http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/11870-accessing-my-nas-after-windows-8-upgrade.html)

---

Try to connect by IP and by name (IE, in explorer, type in \NameOfNas or \NameOfNas\Public or \192.168.1.X or \192.168.1.x\Public)

---

Open up your routers home page and see if both devices are connected (many routers give a graphic image or textual detail what is connected via DHCP).

---

See if you can access the device from another machine to see where the fault is (it could be with the NAS). If another device can access the device, see if you change permissions for your machine.

---

It could be the antivirus or anti'ware, so disable all protection and see if the issue persits.

---

Create a shared folder on another machine and see if your computer can access it to indicate/help prove if the issue is with your machine or not.

---

> You can also try the following command in cmd prompt
>
> > net config server /autodisconnect:-1
>
> Others have reported the following registry editor hacks work (only do
>   this if you know what you're doing)
>
> Apparently you need to tell Windows that you want to use the machine
>   as a file server and that it should allocate resources accordingly.
>
> Set the following registry key to ‘1′:
>
> > HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory
> >     Management\LargeSystemCache
>
> After that navigate too the following key:
>
> > HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size
> >     and set this registry key to ‘3′:

[Source](http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/11870-accessing-my-nas-after-windows-8-upgrade.html)

---

> There is a setting in windows Local Security Policy which is
>   incorrectly set by default for viewing an older communication protocol
>   NAS.
>
> To access said setting go to the control panel in Windows 7, in
>   Category view click on the text "System and Security", then click on
>   the text "Administrative Tools".
>
> Now double click and open "Local Security Policy".
>
> In the Local Security Policy screen on the left navigation tree,
>   expand the "Local Policies --> Security Options" then about 2/3rd's
>   the way down the list you'll see a Policy called "Network Security:
>   LAN Manager authentication level".  Double click and change the
>   setting to be "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if
>   negotiated."
>
> Then just press OK and close all of the open windows and then try
>   again

[Source](http://forums.buffalotech.com/t5/Storage/Windows-7-Pro-can-t-see-my-NAS-Tera-HD-HTGL-5/td-p/21630/page/2)

---

Type in the IP into explorer without the leading `\\`

[Source](http://forums.freenas.org/showthread.php?10319-Windows-8-Connected-Hosts-Can-t-See-FreeNAS-Stored-Files)

---

Use the software it came with (if any) to see if it can automatically detect it for you.

Comment: I can access my files without a problem from Android Jellybean, so the NAS itself works. It seems like windows blocks access even when opening the IP - it doesn't say anything but won't show any options besides a panel called "share", which has been stripped of its content.

Comment: No, I can't map it to the IP. I'll try to change permission through a different device now.

Comment: It doesn't give me any option to change permissions from withing hte NAS control panel. Is there an option like that inside windows I could try changing?

Comment: Can you see all the devices in your routers home page?

Comment: @Severin - see my updated answer, one of the links is fo ryour exact set up

Comment: Got it to work. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a NAS from Windows 8, Try this.. its been tried on a number of PC's without a problem. Edit the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\RequireSecuritySignature
```

and set to 0

Comment: Just wanted to add to winman8 post, this worked for me. It was already 0 but I set it anyways "decimal 0" and it the shares started working after reboot (not sure if it was needed)