# Windows 8 - Mapping Network Drive (NAS)

Tags: windows, windows-8, network-shares, nas

This question has been asked throughout the web, but I am simply not able to get it working.

I am Running Windows 8 Pro (x64), when I connect to the office network, I can connect to all network shares except the ones that is on our (NAS).

As soon as I boot into Windows 7, I am able to connect.

So far I have tried the following:

1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2686098
2. http://help.unc.edu/help/connecting-to-nas-with-windows-8/
3. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/c1d2e480-65e8-41ad-b7a4-73d4ba3ca09d
4. [Windows 8 Pro NAS not recognized?](https://superuser.com/questions/531992/windows-8-pro-nas-not-recognized/531998#531998) (tried all suggestions)

All of the above with no success.

I also tried the `net use` command, to see if it might return additional info, but i get `Error 53`

```
net use k: \\omsmds001\
System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

and

```
net use k: \\10.0.25.3
System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

When i ping the device i get no response

When i try and browse the network location, i get an error:

```
Windows Cannot access \\omsmds001
Error Code: 0x80070035
The network path was not found
```

I have disabled `"SecureNegotiate"` and i can't enable SMB on the device, it is out of my control.

**UPDATE**
I have had some luck here:
I connected to a server that is on the domain, i pinged the server again and received a different IP address. I used that IP address and i am now able to map the disk with the IP. using host name still fails in windows 8.

Comment: Please see my post here on SU http://superuser.com/questions/531992/windows-8-pro-nas-not-recognized/531998#531998

Comment: i tried all those options as well, thanx.

Comment: What is the make of the NAS, and did it come with any software?

Comment: i have no idea, i work for a large corporate (no access to anything). I used a workaround a few months ago that worked, but had to format my pc this weekend, and now i cant find the workaround anymore.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/494893/8672) help?

Comment: i tried all the options... the same solution was posted in point number for above.

Comment: Have you tried to [disable "Secure Negotiate" and enable SMB 2](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/04/windows-8-consumer-preview-cannot-acces-netapp-cifs-share/) ? And what is the exact error message when you try to connect.

Comment: error 53 is a name resolution problem, have you tried net use with the IP Address?     net use \\127.0.0.1  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940100.aspx

Comment: Are other Windows 8 clients able to access the NAS?

Comment: You need to post the exact command you used for net use. Run an nslookup on the hostname you used with that command, and if it resolves to an IP, see if you can contact it via ping.

Comment: i have updated the question with results

Comment: @ditmar, i am not sure what you mean with the nslookup part. I did an nslookup: 'nslookum omsmds001' an i received two servers with seperate ip's

Comment: Try to [Disable the Receive Window Auto Tuning Level](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/72308-auto-tuning-tcp-ip-receive-level.html) : Run as administrator `netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled`.

Comment: (1) What is your machine IP in win7 and win8? Are they on the same subnet? (2) Can Win7 ping the NAS?

Comment: Are you using domain login (active directory) in Windows 7? What about Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

1. IP address

   Check Windows 7 and Windows 8 are using same subnet and gateway. Use following command

   ```
   ipconfig
   ```

   If Windows 7 can ping the device, Windows 8 should be able to also.
2. Turn off firewall

   In file explorer, go to following and turn off firewall

   ```
   Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall
   ```

   If you have other firewall software like norton360, you will have to disable it within those software.
3. Check file sharing is enable

   In file explorer, go to following

   ```
   Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings
   ```

   Under section `All Networks`, check `File sharing connections`, select `Enable file sharing for devices that use 40- or 56-bit encryption`
4. Check remembered credentials

   In file explorer, go to

   ```
   Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager
   ```

   Click `Windows Credentials`. Check if there are credential related to that NAS, delete it.
5. WiFi and Wired

   If you have both w-fi and cable connection, try turn off wi-fi.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you need to map a *share* on a NAS, you cannot map the NAS itself. So try

```
net use k: \\omsmds001\nameOfTheSharedFolder
```

Whether or not your share works with the name (as opposed to the IP address) could depend on various factors, such as

- your DNS setup - does the configured DNS server know about the NAS's name?
- the WINS setup - is there a WINS server in your network
- the Windows Domain setup - are you part of a domain, does the domain controller know the NAS name, does the NAS know your domain controller and is part of the domain

Answer (score 1):

SO my NAS by dlink couldn't be seen wither and Synology help was of no help either.  I tried uninstalling my LAN driver, re-installing it, trying every thing on this forum:

http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=60999&p=250609#p250609

Also enabled SNMP under components/enable windows features

What I think finally helped was this:

Go to System in Win 8. This is really easy on the metro screen type system then in settings its right  there.  (this screen has your Windows Experience rating)

Under Computer name, domain, and work group settings to the right it says change settings.  Clink this.

Under Network ID it will have 2 bubble options: This computer is part of a business netowork or part of a home computer.  I chose HOME COMPUTER option. Restarted and problem solved. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me, Win7 machines could see the NAS drive and shares, Win8 64 Pro could not.

If you can connect to the NAS via IP (e.g. `\\\192.168.0.4` ) try adding an entry to the `hosts` file - it worked for me.

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Add a line with the fixed IP address and device name, e.g.

```
192.168.0.4 NAS
```

now use file explorer to navigate to `\\\NAS`.

Comment: nice idea for editing the hosts file, makes things alot easier if someone sends you a link to the NAS via email

Answer (score 0):

The fix is easy:

- Find your way to the registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\RequireSecuritySignature`
- Set the parameter to `0`

Microsoft acknowledges this issue and has two workarounds: ["System error 2148073478," "extended error," or "Invalid Signature" error on SMB connections in Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2686098/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after recently installing windows 8, and after trying several more or less complicated solutions, what fixed it was the same as [davefromcamp's solution](https://superuser.com/a/563959/153404) (I'm not allowed to upvote yet, but I wanted to share that this worked for me as well, and that it was a really simple solution)!

What made the trick was:

1. Open up "System" from the Control Panel.  One way to access the control panel is to hover the mouse in the right upper or lower corner, slide the cursor to Settings, click, and then select Control Panel from the list. Click "System and Security" and then "System".
2. Under "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings" click the "Change settings" link, located at the right next to an administrator shield icon.
3. On the first tab "Computer name", click the button that says "Network ID..." This opens up a window with only two choices.
4. Select "This is a home computer; it's not part of a business network". Click finish and let windows restart itself.

Hope this can help more people with the same problem!

Comment: I can't quite grasp the topic of the question, but have you considered [editing](http://superuser.com/privileges/edit) the answer you're referring to? :>